# how to get tmp_name of uploaded file in zend framwork

Tags: php, zend-framework, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload image in `amazon s3`. For that i used library in zend.
But issue is that library only accept `$_FILES` variable and `name` and `tmp_name` from that. 
And in my controller, this object is used to get  uploaded image

```
$upload = new \Core\File\Upload("file");
```

Which returns

```
Core\File\Upload Object
(
  [uploadDir] => 
  [allowedExtensions] => 
  [sizeLimit] => 10485760
  [newFileName] => 
  [enableRotateMobile] => 1
  [fileName:Core\File\Upload:private] => png.png
  [fileSize:Core\File\Upload:private] => 28297
  [fileExtension:Core\File\Upload:private] => png
  [savedFile:Core\File\Upload:private] => 
  [errorMsg:Core\File\Upload:private] => 
  [handler:Core\File\Upload:private] => Core\File\Upload\FileUploadXHR Object
    (
        [uploadName] => file
    )

)
```

Which not returns `tmp_name`. and also we cant use `$_FILES` in controller.
any solution?
THanks in advance.

Comment: What is Core\File\Upload?  Modify your class to return tmp_name